# Scalar functions and manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

This paragraph is taken from *Supergravity* book by Freedman and Van Proeyen.he simplest objects to define on a manifold $M$ are scalar functions $f$ that map $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

We say that the point $p$ maps to $f(p)$ = z $\in \mathbb{R}$. On each coordinate patch $M_i$ we can define the compound map $f\circ \phi_i^{-1}$ from $\mathbb{R}^D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as $f_i(x) = f\circ \phi_i^{-1}(x)=z,$ where $x$ stands for {${x^{\mu}}$}. On the overlap $M_i \cap M_j$ of two patches with local coordinates $x^{\mu}$ and $x'^{\nu}$ pf the point $p$, the two descriptions of $f$ must agree. Thus $f_i(x)=f_j(x')$.

To me this is a little bit difficult to imagine and thus comprehend without figures, because I am new to this formal way of illustrating things. *I am of course not asking for figures*.

My question is why was it said that scalar functions are objects on $M$ that "map" $M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I thought objects are not the ones that *map* but rather *charts* are the ones that map.

Another thing is about the second paragraph above, if it could be said in any more informal way I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: This might be better for Math.SE, since these concepts are all purely mathematical

Comment: Are you sure he said a scalar function maps $M \mapsto \mathbb R^n$?  Because one might expect that to be $M \mapsto \mathbb R$ instead.

Comment: My bad! Thank you for dragging my attention to this, I edited the post.

Comment: You think in the wrong way of the word "map". Charts "chart". To map, in math speak, justs means that there is a unique value associated with each point of the preimage. A scalar function does not record the structure of the manifold as a chart does. For example one says a function $f(x, y) = 2x + y$ maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the real numbers.

Comment: @JimtheEnchanter: It's just a semantic confusion about the word *map*. I'm not sure it belongs conclusively to either physics or math.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Actually, it was the *charts* and *manifolds* that led me to the math conclusion as, in this context, these are strictly mathematical objects, albeit with physics applications

Comment: Thank a lot guys for the answers or attempts to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematicians call lots of things maps, but this concept is really no different from a scalar field.  Given a point (which is an element of $M$), the scalar function returns a number (an element of $\mathbb R$).

A chart maps an open set $U \to \mathbb R^n$--for each point on $U$, there is a corresponding point in $\mathbb R^n$.  That's different from $U \to \mathbb R$, which merely says that each point corresponds to some number.  Moreover, the requirements of a chart insist that the chart be one-to-one, while several points on $U$ could correspond to the same number under a scalar field.

---

A more casual way of describing your second paragraph is like so:  given a scalar field on $M$, we can use a coordinate chart to define a corresponding scalar field on $\mathbb R^n$.

Since the scalar field should have a single value at any point on $M$, when multiple charts are used, these can produce scalar fields on different regions of $\mathbb R^n$.  These fields must be equal to each other under the change of chart (coordinates).

Comment: Thank you for answering my first question in a very detailed way, I was wondering if you could help me out with my second part of the question?

Comment: Let me know if that edit is to your liking.

Comment: thank you. I have one more question. As I was rereading this, can you please tell me, why is it that this $f_i(x)=f_j(x')$ must hold?

Comment: Sorry, I've reworded the edit.  Hopefully that makes the answer clear.